# Python: Convert contents of a file to Uppercase characters only

Tags: python

I am trying to convert the contents a set of files to only uppercase characters. Heres the code I have so far:

```
import os

def test():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/David/Files")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    for x in files:
        inputFile = open(x, "r")
        content = inputFile.read()
        with open(x, "wb") as outputFile:
                str.upper(content)
```

When I run it all it does it delete the content of the file.

Comment: Well, where are you writing out the content to the file? You are just opening it in `wb` mode, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't actually writing the contents of the file. Try `outputFile.write(content.upper())`.

```
import os

def test():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/David/Files")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    for x in files:
        inputFile = open(x, "r")
        content = inputFile.read()
        with open(x, "wb") as outputFile:
                outputFile.write(content.upper())
```

When you open a file with `w`, any existing file with that name gets erased (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)). While this is fine, it is your statement `str.upper(content)` that is causing an issue because it doesn't actually do anything to the file - it uppercases `content` but doesn't write it anywhere (note you can also call `.upper()` on the content itself if you want). In order to write the contents to the file, you take the `outputFile` that you created and write `content` to it using the `write()` method. You can also use another `with` statement as you did when writing the file, which will ensure that it also gets properly closed:

```
import os

def test():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/David/Files")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    for x in files:
        with open(x, "r") as inputFile:
            content = inputFile.read()
        with open(x, "wb") as outputFile:
            outputFile.write(content.upper())
```

You could also try opening the file in `r+b` mode, reading and then overwriting by `seek`ing to the beginning of the file and writing (the file length should be the same, but you can use `truncate()` to clear the file after reading if need be):

```
import os

def test():
    x = 'testfile'
    with open(x, "r+b") as inputFile:
        content = inputFile.read()
        inputFile.seek(0)
        inputFile.write(content.upper())
```

Comment: For Python 3, change `"wb"` to `"w"`. Reference: [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in python and CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283178/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-python-and-csv)

Answer (score 1):

```
def test():
os.chdir("C:/Users/David/Files")
files = os.listdir(".")
for x in files:
    inputFile = open(x, "r")
    content = inputFile.read()
    with open(x, "wb") as outputFile:
            outputfile.write(str.upper(content))
            outputfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def test(x):
    with open(x, "r+b") as file:
        content = file.read()
        file.seek(0)
        file.write(content.upper())
```

The above should work if you pass the file name in `x`

Below is command line version to do the same for a single file & you can invoke from the terminal by `ls -1 | parallel python upper.py`

```
import os, sys
with open(sys.argv[1], "r+b") as file:
    content = file.read()
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(content.upper())
```