# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in python and CSV

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I'm getting the above error while executing the below python code to save the HTML table data in a CSV file. How do I get rid of that error?

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://www.mapsofindia.com/districts-india/'
response=requests.get(url)
html=response.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
table=soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'tableizer-table'})
list_of_rows=[]
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    list_of_cells=[]
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        list_of_cells.append(cell.text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
outfile=open('./immates.csv','wb')
writer=csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["SNo", "States", "Dist", "Population"])
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python 3.5: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str)

Answer (score 437, accepted):

You are using Python 2 methodology instead of Python 3.

Change:

```
outfile=open('./immates.csv','wb')
```

To:

```
outfile=open('./immates.csv','w')
```

and you will get a file with the following output:

```
SNo,States,Dist,Population
1,Andhra Pradesh,13,49378776
2,Arunachal Pradesh,16,1382611
3,Assam,27,31169272
4,Bihar,38,103804637
5,Chhattisgarh,19,25540196
6,Goa,2,1457723
7,Gujarat,26,60383628
.....
```

In Python 3 csv takes the input in text mode, whereas in Python 2 it took it in binary mode.

**Edited to Add**

Here is the code I ran:

```
url='http://www.mapsofindia.com/districts-india/'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table=soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'tableizer-table'})
list_of_rows=[]
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    list_of_cells=[]
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        list_of_cells.append(cell.text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
outfile = open('./immates.csv','w')
writer=csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(['SNo', 'States', 'Dist', 'Population'])
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Comment: For use with the `csv` module, the Python 3 `open` should also have `newline=''` as a parameter [[ref](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.reader)]

Comment: Change the 'wb' string to 'w' works for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are using a buffer see [vinyll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41291817/10687003)!

Comment: hi there - i tried out the code - and got back this:` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martin/.atom/python/examples/bs_gumtree_pl.py", line 20, in <module>
    
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 1.415s]` i have no glue what goes on here

Comment: Is there a python2 and python3 compatible way to do this? (I think that whenever a question addresses an issue that results from differences between python2 and python3 it is nice to give a robust version that works in both cases.)

Answer (score 40):

I had the same issue with Python3.
My code was writing into `io.BytesIO()`.

Replacing with `io.StringIO()` solved.

Comment: happens to me with stringio also

Comment: One consideration:  `io.StringIO()` is memory greed and can be a headache with large files.

Answer (score 12):

just change wb to w

```
outfile=open('./immates.csv','wb')
```

to

```
outfile=open('./immates.csv','w')
```

Answer (score 8):

You are opening the csv file in binary mode, it should be `'w'`

```
import csv

# open csv file in write mode with utf-8 encoding
with open('output.csv','w',encoding='utf-8',newline='')as w:
    fieldnames = ["SNo", "States", "Dist", "Population"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(w, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    # write list of dicts
    writer.writerows(list_of_dicts) #writerow(dict) if write one row at time
```

Answer (score 2):

```
file = open('parsed_data.txt', 'w')
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http")}): print (link)
soup_link = str(link)
print (soup_link)
file.write(soup_link)
file.flush()
file.close()
```

In my case, I used BeautifulSoup to write a .txt with Python 3.x. It had the same issue. Just as @tsduteba said, change the 'wb' in the first line to 'w'.

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.  In this case how does this answer differ from the accepted answer?

Comment: @StephenRauch Thank you for your comments. I'm new here and just have started learning Python several weeks ago. I will try to give better answer in the future.

Comment: You can edit this post, and add more detail.  Hit the edit button below and to the left of the post.

Comment: @StephenRauch Thanks for your tips!