# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' with serverless and Python3

Tags: python, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework

I have an aws-lambda function that is triggered whenever a CSV file is uploaded to s3 bucket. I am using serverless framework with Python 3.6, the issue is that i am getting this error message

> a bytes-like object is required, not 'str': TypeError
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/var/task/handler.py", line 33, in csvfile
>
> fichier = obj['Body'].read().split('\n')
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I have did some research in the net [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283178/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-python-and-csv), the issue, is i am not using the open method cause the file is read by s3 event so don't know how to fix it

Here is my code :

```
import logging
import boto3
from nvd3 import pieChart
import sys
import csv


xdata = []
ydata = []
xdata1 = []
ydata1 = []


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def csvfile(event, context):

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')    
    # retrieve bucket name and file_key from the S3 event
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    logger.info('Reading {} from {}'.format(file_key, bucket_name))
    # get the object
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
    # get lines inside the csv
    fichier = obj['Body'].read().split('\n')
    #print lines
     for ligne in fichier:
        if len(ligne) > 1:
            logger.info(ligne.decode())
            liste = ligne.split(',')
            print(liste)
            if liste[2] == 'ByCateg':
                xdata.append(liste[4]) 
                ydata.append(liste[1]) 
            elif liste[2] == 'ByTypes':
                xdata1.append(liste[4]) 
                ydata1.append(liste[1]) 

         print ' '.join(xdata) 

print('Function execution Completed')
```

and here is my serverless.yml code:

```
service: aws-python # NOTE: update this with your service name

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
              - s3:*
              - "ses:SendEmail"
              - "ses:SendRawEmail"
              - "s3:PutBucketNotification"
          Resource: "*"

    functions:
  csvfile:
    handler: handler.csvfile
    description: send mail whenever a csv file is uploaded on S3 
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: car2
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - suffix: .csv
```

Comment: Please post the whole traceback

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i have just did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that

```
fichier = obj['Body'].read()
```

returns a `bytes` object, not a string. This is because the encoding may require more than a single character. Now you're using `split` on a `bytes` object, but you can't split it using a string, you need to split using another `bytes` object. Specifically

```
fichier = obj['Body'].read().split(b'\n')
```

should fix your error, but depending on what you're expecting maybe decoding is more appropriate before the split?

```
fichier = obj['Body'].read().decode("utf-8").split('\n')
```

Comment: i already try this before, i am getting this error message :   'str' object has no attribute 'decode': AttributeError
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/task/handler.py", line 38, in csvfile
    logger.info(ligne.decode())
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: That's a different problem. You converted `fichier` to string with that last decode, and I'm guessing somewhere else in your code you passed it as is, but a bytes object is expected - I'm not going to debug for you, the stack should help. You can just stay with bytes all over - use the first version, and use `bytes` everywhere.

Comment: @kabanus, this solution worked for me. I was reading the data from the S3 file and getting error to split the data because of byte format.