# how to write a list into csv file

Tags: python, list

I tried the below code to write a list to csv file, but it always shows the error:

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Below is the code:

```
import csv
a=['a','b','c']
with open(r"result.csv",'wb') as resultFile:
    writer = csv.writer(resultFile, lineterminator='\n')
    for i in a:
        writer.writerows([[i]])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in python and CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283178/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-python-and-csv)

Answer (score 4):

you [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) your file in 'binary' mode instead of 'text' mode:

```
with open(r"result.csv",'w') as resultFile:  # instead of 'wb'
```

should work.

Comment: what is the difference between "w" and "wb"

Comment: [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) in my answer is a link to the documentation; also this may help: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Don't answer duplicate question. 
 This is exact duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283178/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-python-and-csv

Answer (score 0):

Like @hiro protagonist said, you are opening the file in binary mode. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is some helpful documentation.

> Python distinguishes between binary and text I/O. Files opened in binary mode (including 'b' in the mode argument) return contents as [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) objects without any decoding. In text mode (the default, or when 't' is included in the mode argument), the contents of the file are returned as [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), the bytes having been first decoded using a platform-dependent encoding or using the specified encoding if given.

You could also use pandas [to_csv](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.to_csv('result.csv', header=None, index=False)
```