# RobotFramework :CSV Library : Error while writing into CSV

Tags: csv, robotframework

I am using Robotframework and CSVLibrary to write randomly generated strings. Error while writing into CSV . The following is the code,

```
${datalist}   CREATE LIST
${list}=        getmandatory              test.xml     testInfo
        : FOR    ${a}    IN  @{list}
                \   ${random}=    String.Generate Random String     ${a.maxlength}      [UPPER]${a.format}
                \   append to list    ${datalist}      ${random}
        log to console   ${datalist}
        append to csv file      data.csv     ${datalist}
```

The getmandatory is a python pgm wshich returns me a list of all mandatory fields in a given xml. The list values are randomly generated strings , ['BDSVRtZEISBGItUtUMYHBULtUEZQTtDOCBFUGJAPWHXtIeYKTUAWOLSPFBXQCDWLtTIPtOJFTBXSUAYMMNtPRRFMQZGXKBUAtIFD', 'DHeSR']

I am getting an error ,

> **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here . Please help !

Comment: Please don't post a link to a picture of code. Take the time to copy, paste, and format the code in your question.

Comment: Sorry. Updated the question.

Comment: Which line is the error occurring? I usually prefer to write Robot keywords just as high level sentences in English, and leaving `for`s for Python code

Comment: Error is happening at “ append to csv file”

Comment: Are you using python3?

Comment: I am ! I did the change as suggested below and things are looking good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue with CSVLibrary and python3.

In CSVLibrary/**init**.py you'll find the following function.

```
@staticmethod
def _open_csv_file_for_write(filename, data, csv_writer=csv.writer, **kwargs):
    with open(filename, 'ab') as csv_handler:
        writer = csv_writer(csv_handler, **kwargs)
```

Change this to: ('a' instead of 'ab')

```
@staticmethod
def _open_csv_file_for_write(filename, data, csv_writer=csv.writer, **kwargs):
    with open(filename, 'a') as csv_handler:
        writer = csv_writer(csv_handler, **kwargs)
```

In Python 3 unicode strings are the default and you can't write them in binary mode.

See [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in python and CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283178/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-python-and-csv)

Comment: I did the change as suggested and the data got appended to the csv file. Thank you so much.

Comment: The problem right now is, each character in a list value is getting written in to each column. G|O|D| instead of GOD in one single column