# Python 2 and 3 csv module text-binary mode backwards compatibility

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, backwards-compatibility

I would like to create a code which is Python 2.7-3.6 compatible I am trying to fix a problem with the csv module where initially I used `outfile=open('./test.csv','wb')` in Python 2.7 now I have to use `outfile=open('./test.csv','w')` [like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283178/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-python-and-csv) otherwise I will incur in a 
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.

A the moment I am fixing it using this code:

```
import sys
w = 'w'
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
   w = 'wb'
# Where needed
outfile=open('./test.csv',w)
```

Not very nice, is there any better solution for opening the file in 'wb' if I am using Python 2.7 and in `w` if I am using Python 3.x? To clarify I have to use `wb` in Python 2.7 because otherwise, I'll have a blank line every time I add a new line to a file.

Answer (score 3):

When opening files to be used with module `csv` on *python 3* you *always* should add `newline=""` the the open statement:

```
import sys
mode = 'w'
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
   mode  = 'wb'

# python 3 write 
with open("somefile.txt", mode, newline="") as f:
    pass  # do something with f
```

The `newline` parameter **does not exist in python 2** - but if you skip it in *python 3* you get misshaped csv output on windows with additional empty lines in it.

See [csv.writer (python 3)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

> If *csvfile* is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`.  If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use `\r\n` linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added. It should always be safe to specify `newline=''`, since the *csv module* does its own (universal) newline handling.

---

You should use a contextmanaging `with` as well:

```
with open("somefile.txt", mode) as f:  # works in 2 and 3
    pass  # do something with f
```

to get your filehandles closed even if you run into some kind of exception. This is python 2 safe - see [Methods of file objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is also much shorter than writing equivalent `try-finally` blocks.

---

Your solution - ugly but works:

```
import sys
python3 = sys.version_info[0] >= 3 

if python3:
    with open("somefile.txt","w",newline="") as f:
        pass
else:
    with open("somefile.txt","wb") as f:
        pass
```

The problem is the *parameter* `newline` does not exist in python 2. To fix that you would have to wrap/monkypath `open(..)` including the contextmanaging.

Comment: Thank Patrick, yes that's why I have this problem and I want to fix it, and yes I use `with`statements, I didn't put in the working example only for brevity. I think however you answer doesn't answer to my question and it's wrong because the code you wrote won't work inpython2.7.

Comment: Nowhere in the question you linked is _any_ mentioning of `newline=""` - there is one comment on the accepted answer that mentions it. The linked question is about `'wb'` vs `'w'` and str vs bytelike objects (as is yours) - not about the resulting problems of omitting `newline=""` like f.e. here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row). Going to delete this answer in a bit as it seems not related to your problems.

Comment: I did not say anything about `newline` I just tested your solution and it did not solve my problem, with your edit now at least answer my question so I've upvoted, I did not want to be rude, just trying to solve a problem and give a feedback