# Count the duplicate rows in excel using python and i am getting error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

Format Like this email excel file

```
name       email
A          A@gmail.com
B          B@gmailcom
C          c@gmail.com
A          A@gmail.com
B          B@gmail.com
```

In second excel file outfile.csv This is the output

```
name       email               count
    A          A@gmail.com         2
    B          B@gmailcom          2
    C          c@gmail.com          1
```

This is python code First, I read the excel file

```
data_file=pd.read_excel('email.xlsx')
writer = csv.writer(open('outfiles.csv','wb'))
code = defaultdict(int)
for row in data_file:
    code[row[0]] += 1
# now write the file
for row in code.items():
   writer.writerow(row)
```

Error:

> writer.writerow(row) TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not
>   'str'

I am getting this error so could you please help me out.

Comment: Open the file `open('outfiles.csv','w')` without the `b` character (you don't want byte file mode)

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283178/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-python-and-csv .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to count the duplicates, use pandas.DataFrame.unique()!

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('email.xlsx') 
unique = data.column_name.unique() 
duplicates = len(data)-len(unique)
print("number of duplicate rows is:",duplicates)
```

you just need to know the column_name, you can see all using `print(data.columns)`

Comment: Almost. You need to use the `DataFrame.duplicated()` method to count duplicated rows. `unique()` will include rows where just one exists in the `DataFrame`