# type error while writing header to a file : python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

the code was running fine with python2 but failing in python3.

```
with open(inputpath + 'company.csv', 'wb') as outcsv:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outcsv, delimiter='|',
                                fieldnames=columnlist, quotechar='"',
                                quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writeheader()
```

Error which I am getting :

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Any help would be be appreciated!

Comment: Use `w` instead of `wb` while opening file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in python and CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283178/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-python-and-csv)